# Pandas remove columns from one dataframe that are not in the index of another dataframe - error TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to get the indexes from a data frame (df in make_results) and ensure that only the indexes are columns in two other data frames (X_train, X_test).

But am currently getting the error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

This is for multiple data frames within a list.

So for these data frames: 
[Dataframes X_Train and T_test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuw7X.png)

I would like them to only have columns that match these indexes:
[Indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhJ2Q.png)

```py
# Remove variables with no relationship from the X_train and X_test data for each make
for X_train, X_test in zip([t[0] for t in makes_train_test_sets], 
                            [t[1] for t in makes_train_test_sets]):
    # Remove test and training data any insignificant variables
    X_train = X_train.filter(df.index.values for df in make_results)
    X_test = X_test.filter(df.index.values for df in make_results)
```

For datasets X_train  and X_test, the only columns left should be those that are indexed in df.index.values for df in make_results.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, then it seems you're using `filter` the wrong way.

If you simply want to know how to filter out columns in a dataframe that exist as the index of another, you need to use:

```py
X_train.filter(df.index)
```

If you want to iterate over all the dataframes in an iterable and filter one by one:

```py
for X_train, X_test in zip([t[0] for t in makes_train_test_sets], 
                            [t[1] for t in makes_train_test_sets]):
    for df in mask_results:
        X_train = X_train.filter(df.index)
        X_test = X_test.filter(df.index)
```

You could also, previously "acquire" all the indices of these dataframes and filter by that only once:

```py
index_set = set()
for df in mask_results:
    index_set = index_set.union(df.index)

for X_train, X_test in zip([t[0] for t in makes_train_test_sets], 
                            [t[1] for t in makes_train_test_sets]):
    X_train = X_train.filter(index_set)
    X_test = X_test.filter(index_set)
```

Comment: Thanks Zionsof. I probably didn't articulate that one well.  I need to loop through each dataframe in make_results (for df in make_results) and pull out each dataframes index and then loop through each tuple in makes_train_test_set list (which has a matching index with make_results) and ensure columns in tuple 0 and tuple 1 match the indexes in make_results.

Comment: Then I think you'll simply need my second solution wrapped in your original `for`. I'll update

Comment: That runs but it doesn't drop drop any columns in the X_train, X_test.  Why did you pick a set instead of a list?  I tried making a list of lists for each index using `# Get a list of significant variables for each make
make_results_significant_variables = []
for df in make_results:
    make_results_significant_variables.append(df.index.tolist())` but it came back with an error **TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'**

Comment: Hard to know without the full code you provided, something still has to do with a set, what you wrote here works on my end. It may also not drop columns since maybe all the columns are correct. The data image you provide isn't too helpful (As they are also both the same image)

Answer (score 0):

I could not call a list of a list in Pandas for some reason and was having trouble editing the Tuples.  In the end I created a copy of my list of tuples with dataframes and series:

```
# Drop anything not significant from make_results
for datas in make_results:
    datas.drop(datas.loc[datas['P>|z|'] > .05].index, inplace=True)


def remove_others(t, cols):
    tuple_list = list(t)
    tuple_list[0] = tuple_list[0][cols]
    tuple_list[1] = tuple_list[1][cols]
    return tuple(tuple_list)


new_train_test_sets = []

list_index = 0

#for df in make_results:
for t in makes_train_test_sets:
    new_train_test_sets.append(remove_others(t, make_results[list_index].index.values))
    list_index += 1


makes_train_test_sets = new_train_test_sets
```